# Creating a record does not appear to persist to the test database, rspec, factory_girl_rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

According to the [factory_girl_rails](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) documentation: here is the difference between the factory_girl `build()` and `create()` methods:

> # Returns a User instance that's not saved
>
> user = build(:user)
>
> # Returns a saved User instance
>
> user = create(:user)

I know the power of factories is that they make your test suite fast because it allows you to run tests without having to touch the database at all via the `build()` method.  The `create()` method on the other hand does still touch the database because it persists the record to the database.

I am confused because when I put a break point within my test after using `create()`

- The rails console says that the object is persisted to the database *(as expected)*
- The `test/test.log` show that the object was persisted to the database *(as expected)*
- But when I look at the table within the test database: It is not there *(not expected. I would expect to see the object within the database)*

  ```
  #someApp/spec/models/user_spec.rb
  RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
    it "checks the age on the basic 'User' Factory " do
      user = create(:user) # should create a user and persist it to the database
      binding.pry
      expect(user.age).to eq(28)
    end
  end
  ```

Execution stops at the break point and the rails console opens up.  I test for persistence and it returns true:

```
user.persisted? 
  => true
```

However, I look within my test database at the table, refresh the table, and yet still no record is shown:

[image: record does not display in table]

What am I missing?  I thought that when you use `create()` the record will be persisted to the database.  Does it actually not save to the database at all?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

RSpec runs tests in transactions. This means that before a test starts a transaction is opened and after the test is done it's rolled back. This way the test interfaces with the DB but no data is visible from outside the transaction (so from outside RSpec process)

Comment: hmm.  I guess I was thinking that since my `binding.pry` was inside the transaction that I would be able to peek at the object within the table before it was rolled back since the transaction was not finished yet.  I guess that is not possible?

Comment: No, because as I said rows "in transaction" which was not yet committed are invisible from the outside.